# Calling net.tcp WCF service failed

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-11

I have wcf service running on localhost:53201 withing local IIS.
[image]

when I am trying to request this service I get exception:
`Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:53201/Calculator.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:04.1811447. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:53201.`

I was trying to enable WCF services running powershell script:

```
#.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
    #Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation /all
    #Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-NonHTTP-Activation /all
#.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services & WCF
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4-AdvSrvs /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-Pipe-Activation45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-MSMQ-Activation45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-NonHTTP-Activation /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-Services45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-TCP-Activation45 /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-TCP-PortSharing45 /all
```

The operation was completed successfully for all of them, nevertheless, it does not help.
Could you please advise me what I may doing wrong here or what else may I try?

**Edit:**

looks like I do not have following services in Services list:
[image]
but I do not know how to add them as all Windows Features I am aware I should I have already enabled as follow:[image]

Comment: What is `telnet localhost 53201` showing? Or you can try to see if some application is listening on this port with `netstat -a`. Also please check IIS logs if you see any traces of incoming requests. Firewall or antivirus can block connections.

Comment: PS C:\ESW-Development\Tfs> telnet localhost 53201
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 53201: Connect failed

Comment: What about HTTP binding? Can you check `http://localhost:51201/Calculator.svc` in the browser?

Comment: There is no binding on that port `53201` for http. Instead, port exposed for HTTP is `51201`. It returns WSDL definition when I add proper route.

Comment: `netstat -a | find "53201"` does not return any result.

Comment: Then I would check firewall and antivirus.

Comment: Unfortunately, I enabled TCP traffic on that port, I have checked the antivirus events and I do see the same behavior - cann't make the connection. Maybe I should have those `Net.Tcp Listener Adapter` and `Net.Tcp Port Sharing` visible as running in `services.msc`, but I was not able to see them even after enabling WCF Windows features.